# How to monitor container app metrics in azure

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-container-apps

I'm new to the azure environment and wondering how it's possible to monitor an azure container app? Currently I've deployed a nodejs application by running a container app and I know how to query some logs by using the protocols section.

What I'm really looking into is how to get metrics like incoming requests or vcpu usage but I don't know how to get those metrics using azure monitoring.

How can I access those values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to add Azure application insights SDK to your nodejs project. It will monitor your app activity like incoming/outcoming requests, database operations and etc. Also there is an option to add automatic metrics gathering:

See this [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs) for details.

```
let appInsights = require("applicationinsights");
appInsights.setup("<instrumentation_key>")
    .setAutoDependencyCorrelation(true)
    .setAutoCollectRequests(true)
    .setAutoCollectPerformance(true, true)
    .setAutoCollectExceptions(true)
    .setAutoCollectDependencies(true)
    .setAutoCollectConsole(true)
    .setUseDiskRetryCaching(true)
    .setSendLiveMetrics(true)
    .start();
```